# How to run Grunt tasks from within VSCode?

Tags: gruntjs, visual-studio-code

Title says it all. I still use Grunt, though it feels like I should be using Gulp.

Nonetheless, rather than alt-tabbing to a CMD window, I'd like to use the palette or shortcut keys to kick off some Grunt tasks. Reading the docs, it looks like I'd need to write a json task. What??? That's like writing a Grunt task to run a Grunt task.

Has anybody else already written a generic VSCode task for running Grunt?

EDIT:
Thanks to the accepted answer, here is what I'm running:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0", 
    "command": "grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [{
        "taskName": "default"
    },{
        "taskName": "stage"
    },{
        "taskName": "dist"
    }]
}
```

I open the palette, and see default, stage, dist. Not sure if that's the best way, but it works so far. Definitely room for improvement.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using VSCode version 0.1.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the default `tasks.json` file, you can just modify the gulp example to be used for grunt. In my current project, I just need to run `grunt` in the root directory, so mine looks like this:

```
{
    "command": "grunt",
    "isShellCommand": true
}
```

You can also modify the existing `tasks` option to add specific tasks to run in your build.

Comment: It should be noted that `isShellCommand` was deprecated in 1.14. Instead, you should switch it with `"type": "shell"`.

Answer (score 15):

The most recen update to VSC has auto-detects grunt (and gulp tasks) so you can now just use `cmd+p` then type `task` (notice the space at the end) and VSC will show you the available tasks to run.

[image: This is how it looks]

More info at: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 3):

Now (version 1.24.1+), there is a Tasks Menu.  Run Task will give you a list.

[image: Tasks menu]

Comment: V 1.31+ has it under the Terminal menu now.